# Equation of graph and conic section

Tags: conic-sections

If graph of the equation $x^3 +3x^2y +3xy^2 +y^3 -x^2+y^2=0$
comprises of a line and a conic section .

I am confused how can we find the equation of line and conic section separately .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Your equation is reducable to $$(x+y)^3=(x+y)(x-y)$$
$$(x+y)(x^2+y^2+2xy-x+y)=0$$

I gues you can seperate line and conic now

Comment: A line and circle through the origin.

Comment: @Narasimham the line is through origin. But the conic is certainly not a circle.

Comment: Yes, it is a product of a parabola flaring down towards southeast passing through $(0,0),(1,0),(0,1)$ and line $x=y$ as axis.